# Improving performance of a while loop (C# code) calling a T-SQL stored procedure

Tags: c#, t-sql, iis-7, application-pool

The following SqlCommand works fine with no apparent performance issues, when the stored procedure SelectNewObjects returns few (~500) records. However, when it returns more than 1,000 records, I start experiencing performance issues:

```
using (SqlCommand cmdAddNewObject = new SqlCommand("SelectNewObjects", con))
{
    cmdAddNewObject.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmdAddNewObject.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parameter1", parameter1);
    using (SqlDataReader rdrAddNewObject = cmdAddNewObject.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (rdrAddNewObject.Read())
        {
            if (rdrAddNewObject.GetString(0) != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    addObject(parameter1, rdrAddNewObject.GetString(0), rdrAddNewObject.GetString(0).Length / 4, rdrAddNewObject.GetString(0).Substring(0, 2),
                        rdrAddNewObject.GetString(0).Substring(2, 2), rdrAddNewObject.GetString(1));
                    if (rdrAddNewObject.GetString(1) == "No description found")
                    {
                        // Do something
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Do something else
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    // Throw exception
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In simple words, what I am doing here is call a method (**addObject**) for each record that is returned by **SelectNewObjects**.

A couple of details:

- **SelectNewObjects** returns records from a temporary table created off **Table1**.
- In the **if / else** block I am updating a field of **Table1** of the related record in the temporary table after the execution of **addObject** completes.
- The addObject method inserts each record found in the SQL temporary table in a separate Oracle system through the use of SOA (Service-Oriented Architecture). I was not given access to the underlying DB, so I had to settle with this way of doing things instead.
- There are times when the temporary table is expected to have more than 20,000 records (only two fields each: *Name* and *Description*) so this can quickly become a nightmare.

At one point, the application pool will fail with the following two errors (taken from the IIS 7 Windows Event Viewer):

- **Event ID 5013:** *A process serving application pool '.NET v4.5' exceeded time limits during shut down. The process id was '5616'*.
- **Event ID 5138:** *A worker process '5616' serving application pool '.NET v4.5' failed to stop a listener channel for protocol 'http' in
  the allotted time.  The data field contains the error number*.

The description of those event IDs in technet.microsoft.com and support.microsoft.com do not shed too much light on this performance issue and is not conclusive as to its root cause.

That said, is there any way to improve the C# code to handle tens of thousands of records returned by the SP, and perform an action on each one faster?

Comment: If the bottleneck in C# code for sure? What's the timings if you were to execute same stored procedure in Management Studio?

Comment: Divide the problem in two: comment out the interior of the `while` loop and see if the stored procedure and data retrieval times are acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming this is because it's taking a long time to insert into the oracle DB over the wire as well as keeping your SQL connection open longer than it should be open. Therefore you will want to store your data in a temp collection THEN either loop through the list or send it as bulk (if you do the latter you will need to break it up or you will hit a limit)

eg

```
    List<ObjectToStoreInOracle> items = new List<ObjectToStoreInOracle>();

    using (SqlCommand cmdAddNewObject = new SqlCommand("SelectNewObjects", con))
    {
        cmdAddNewObject.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmdAddNewObject.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parameter1", parameter1);
        using (SqlDataReader rdrAddNewObject = cmdAddNewObject.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (rdrAddNewObject.Read())
            {
                if (rdrAddNewObject.GetString(0) != null)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        // add items to temp array list
                        items.Add(new ObjectToStoreInOracle(parameter1, rdrAddNewObject.GetString(0), rdrAddNewObject.GetString(0).Length / 4, rdrAddNewObject.GetString(0).Substring(0, 2), rdrAddNewObject.GetString(0).Substring(2, 2), rdrAddNewObject.GetString(1))))  

                        if (rdrAddNewObject.GetString(1) == "No description found")
                        {
                            // Do something
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // Do something else
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        // Throw exception
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    AddToOracleDB(items)


    private void AddToOracleDB(List<ObjectToStoreInOracle> items){

    //do stuff here to add to the Oracle DB
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip of storing the data in a List object - I did that and I am no longer experiencing these issues for this particular SP. I will replicate this solution in another part of the code (another while loop invoking an INSERT query to the SQL DB) to improve that as well. Thanks again!